# How to retrieve google speech api asynchronous request response ?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm trying to make the asynchronous google-speech-api request work.
As advised I use `play` command:

`play audio2min.flac`

[image]

Using the code from here : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api-client. I then adapt the request with corresponding encoding.

I then get the error :

```
"Audio 'content' cannot be longer than 1 min.
For long audio, use the 'uri' parameter to specify a file."
```

I then put my file in google storage and adapt my request with `"uri": "gs://path/to/my/audio2min.flac"`

But then I get the error :

```
For audio inputs longer than 1 min, please use LINEAR16 encoding.
```

The problem is : When I change the encoding for LINEAR16 instead of FLAC, I get a void answer.

To make sure encoding was really the problem, I tried with a 30sec sample from my file with the synchronous requests. It worked with encoding FLAC but not with encoding LINEAR16.

Can anybody explain me how what should I do from here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work by changing the encoding of my file.

1. Download audacity : http://www.audacityteam.org/
2. Open your file
3. In File -> Export Audio -> Choose :

`other uncompressed files`

Header : `RAW`

Encoding : `16-bit PCM`

[image]

Now it should work